# Flutter streambuilder - summarize all items with the same value of a document and show the number

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to summarize all items with the same value of a document and show the number.
Is it generally possible to use forEach in a streambuilder? I can't make it

db structure:
+messages

- Item1 A
- Item2 C
- Item3 C
- Item4 A
- Item5 B
  ...

In this case the answer should be:

- A 2
- B 1
- C 2

Code:

```
Widget myWidget() {
  return StreamBuilder(
      stream
      : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages")
            .doc("messages")
            .snapshots(),
        builder
      : (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container();
        } else {
          var userDocument = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot ? ;
          // here I would like to summarize all values with the same value and
          // show the number
          int countA = ...;
          int countB = ...;
          int countC = ...;
          return Column(children
                        : [
                          Text("A"),
                          Text(countA.toString()),
                          Text("B") Text(countB.toString()),
                          Text("C") Text(countC.toString()),
                        ], );
        }
      });
}
```